# GWT GXT StoreFilterField event

Tags: java, gwt, filter, tree, gxt

I would like to search into my tree only if the user type 3 character at least.
How i can catch "doSelect" event to do this?
If i add a keylistener on the text field to check its value, the handler is invoked after the doSelect.
Can anyone help me?

This is an example...

```
    filterText = new StoreFilterField<ModelData>() {

        @Override
        protected boolean doSelect(Store<ModelData> store,
                ModelData parent, ModelData record, String property,
                String filter) {

                String name = record.get("name");
                name = name.toLowerCase();
                if (name.startsWith(filter.toLowerCase())) 
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
        }

    };

    KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() {
        public void componentKeyUp(ComponentEvent event) {
            loadingImage.setVisible(false);
            if(filterText.isValid() && filterText.getRawValue().length()>=FILTER_MIN_SIZE) {
                filterText.bind(store);
            } else {
                filterText.unbind(store);
            }

        }

    }; 
    filterText.setMinLength(FILTER_MIN_SIZE);
    filterText.bind(store);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Appears to be GXT 2, let me know if you are actually using GXT 3)

`StoreFilterField` relies on the `applyFilters` method to actually apply all of these. It has a check already that the text has at least one character:

```
protected void applyFilters(Store<M> store) {
  if (getRawValue().length() > 0) {
    store.addFilter(filter);
    store.applyFilters(property);
  } else {
    store.removeFilter(filter);
  }
}
```

The easiest way I see to override this would be to subclass `StoreFilterField` and redefine this method:

```
filterText = new StoreFilterField<ModelData>() {
  @Override
  protected void applyFilters(Store<M> store) {
    if (getRawValue().length() > 3) {
      store.addFilter(filter);
      store.applyFilters(getProperty());
    } else {
      store.removeFilter(filter);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect! There is also a method to intercept the end of the search? It's a big ModelData and i would like to display a progress bar...

Comment: Hi, maybe you can help me with this question... http://stackoverflow.com/q/15006376/2055624